# How to open default share C$ in Windows 10 home?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, shared-folders

I would like to be able to connect remotely to `\\myw10pc\c$\` (Windows 10 Home x64, v 1709) from another PC on the LAN, but I am not having success - any username I try (*e.g.* `.\conrad`, `myw10pc\conrad`, `conrad` - this account does have local admin rights) is not working.  I am able to do this on my Win 7 Pro PCs.  Is this a limitation of the Home edition, or am I missing some setting allowing this functionality?

I have tried disabling the Private/Domain networks firewalls, but that does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C$ is an administrative share reserved for domains. Given that a home edition is not able to join a domain, the C$ share is not present by default either.

In order to use such share, create a new share of the C drive, and if you want the share to be hidden, add a $ to the end.

For example: `MyC$` can be used and then you can use `\\myw10pc\MyC$` to access it.

Comment: C$ is not reserved for domains - I can access it without a problem on my non-domain Win7 Pro PCs

Comment: That's because Windows 7 Pro can work with domain type shares. But Home versions can't. They cannot even join a domain. That's why you need to recreate the share if you want to use it.

Comment: Adding a new hidden share for C did it

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that the Administrative shares only exist on the Professional/Business editions of Windows. They're not a domain-specific feature.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator good point. Edited my post. :)